# iOS draw the table in pdf document

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

I will create the pdf from the contents of UIViewController.
When UIViewController has a table region(the same as Excel), I didn't find the method for drawing an table in pdf document.
Does anyone know to solve this problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy method of creating a table I know of if you're using a Quartz graphics context (CGContextRef type).  I was able to create a table programmatically by drawing lines on the PDF in nested for loops, and by paying careful attention to spacing to make it look right.

Psuedo-code:

```
for (int i=0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
{
// display each row
    // Draw row line
    CGPoint horizontalRowDivider[2] = {CGPointMake(x_startPoint, y_startPoint + (i * row_width)), CGPointMake(x_endPoint, y_endPoint + (i * row_width))};
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(pdfContext, newlineItemDivider, 2);


    for(int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++)
    {
         //Draw each column cell
         const char *desc_text = "Table value"
         CGContextShowTextAtPoint (pdfContext, x_cellDataLoc, y_cellDataLoc, desc_text, strlen(desc_text));
         CGPoint verticalLineCellDivider[2] = {CGPointMake(x_startPoint + (j * col_width), y_startPoint), CGPointMake(x_endPoint + (j * col_width), y_endPoint)};
         CGContextStrokeLineSegments(pdfContext, verticalLineCellDivider, 2);  
    }


}
```

This is a rough example of the kind of logic you might use to draw a table.  You'll probably want a rectangle, or a border, around your table to make it look right, among any other kinds of tweaks to make it how you want.  You can find the list of methods on how to do that and more through the below link.  I know this probably isn't what you had in mind, but I hope this gives you some direction to take if you were totally stuck.  Good luck!

You can find the full library of functions available for drawing PDFs in Apple's documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html