# How can I make a PDF document containing a table of data on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf

I need a way of creating a table of data in landscape mode. This table should be in PDF form, is this possible on iPhone? If so please can someone advise on how to do it? If not, what are my other options?

Comment: There's something relevant in the iOS documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-CJBHHJCB but it's a fairly low-level API. (Essentially you can do Quartz 2D drawing into a PDF page.) You could also try [PDFlib](http://pdflib.com/) but I think it costs money for non-open-source applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your table in UIWebView and then follow this link to make pdf from UIWebView

http://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/making-a-pdf-from-a-uiwebview/

Answer (score 2):

I believe following link would definitely help you to create table using `drawLine` method in a loop. You can simply modify the `drawLine` method and implement to draw table for you. Also the code is very Handy to use with a very customizable methods for PDF creation.

http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/

For more help you can refer [previous post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821085/ios-draw-the-table-in-pdf-document)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is using HTML. You can do all the text processing in objective-C and display the table in a simple `UIWebView`. This also gives you great control over how it is going to look.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How would I go about displaying my HTML in the UIWebView? Also; is it possible to create a PDF document out of the data displayed in the UIWebView?

Comment: Just checkt the [UIWebView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It is really simple with `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`. Now you do not need the PDF.